# Performance comparison: WriteAllText vs AppendAllLines

Tags: c#, string, performance

I have a program that writes thousands of records into a text file. I have the following two ways of writing records:

Using WriteAllText:

```
string demandASCIIStrings = "";

foreach (Demands myDemands in demandList)
{
    demandASCIIStrings += $"{myDemands.DEVICETYPE},"; //DeviceType
    demandASCIIStrings += $"{myDemands.DEVICENUMBER},"; //DeviceNumber
    demandASCIIStrings += $"{myDemands.LOCATION},"; //MeterLocation
    demandASCIIStrings += $"{myDemands.METERINDEX},"; //MeterIndex
    demandASCIIStrings += $"{myDemands.LOSSESPERPHASE},"; //LossesPerPhase
    demandASCIIStrings += $"{myDemands.LoadModelName},"; //LoadModelName
    demandASCIIStrings += $"{myDemands.DEMANDTYPE},"; //DemandType
    demandASCIIStrings += $"{myDemands.AAmp}" + System.Environment.NewLine); //Aamp
}
File.WriteAllText(targetFileName, demandASCIIStrings);
```

Using AppendAllLines:

```
List<string> demandASCIIStrings = new List<string>();

foreach (Demands myDemands in demandList)
{
    demandASCIIStrings.Add(
    $"{myDemands.DEVICETYPE}," + //DeviceType
    $"{myDemands.DEVICENUMBER}," + //DeviceNumber
    $"{myDemands.LOCATION}," + //MeterLocation
    $"{myDemands.METERINDEX}," + //MeterIndex
    $"{myDemands.LOSSESPERPHASE}," + //LossesPerPhase
    $"{myDemands.LoadModelName}," + //LoadModelName
    $"{myDemands.DEMANDTYPE}," + //DemandType
    $"{myDemands.AAmp}"); //Aamp
}
File.AppendAllLines(targetFileName, demandASCIIStrings);
```

The WriteAllText took 30 seconds to complete, whereas AppendAllLines took less than a second. Can someone explain the difference between the two, and explain why the second way is significantly faster than the first? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because in the first one you are repeatedly appending to an (eventually) enormous string, and in the second you are appending only 8 items to a string (even though in a loop). Replace the `demandASCIIStrings` string in the first one with `StringBuilder` and marvel at the difference.

Comment: As mentioned by @MatthewWatson, string concatenation can become a performance issue when there are lots of them. This is because a new string is created for each concatenation. You may also want to try writing directly to the file rather than using an intermediate buffer (string or list in your 2 examples).

Comment: Note that `AppendAllLines` and `WriteAllText` *behave differently*.  One is appending to the end the other is replacing the contents of the file.  There are of course WriteXXX/AppendXXX methods for both lines and text, so you have all of the options.

Comment: In the first snippet, it's the loop that takes a lot of time, not the writing to the file.

Comment: The best approach in this case is to forego both the string concatenation (slow, as others have explained) and the list construction and instead to just write the strings manually with a `StreamWriter`. You're going to allocate way fewer temporary strings.